# Random value for disk Signature

Tags: wmi, disk, disk-partitioning, wql

As part of a machine identification system, I'm looking for the Signature of the Win32_DiskDrive.  On two customer's machines now, I've seen this field have a random value.  I assume that is due to not having checked the HRESULT in the shipped code.

What would cause a machine to not have a valid signature?

WQL query: SELECT Caption, DeviceID, Signature, TotalSectors FROM Win32_DiskDrive

*Update:*

This has now been seen on 3 machines, one in China, one in Eastern Europe, and one in Canada.  When I say it returns a random value, I mean it returns a different random value every time it is queried.  Waiting on a customer to try diskpart and see what it says when the uniqueid is requested.

Comment: Wonder if this is more of a Super User question

Comment: The problem is tied to GPT instead of MBR partition style.  Will provide a more complete answer when I finish working on my problem.

Comment: While I can see how one might think this question is about general hardware, I see no difference between this question and any SQL question. The WQL is a tool used by developers to get information about the machine being used.

Comment: Also, there are many WMI questions on stackoverflow already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to determine that the Signature was null.

My solution was to iterate through the partitions for the disk drive

```
wstring partionquery= L"ASSOCIATORS of {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='";
partionquery += disk_deviceid;
partionquery += L"'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
```

Retrieve the Type value and see if it starts with "GPT" and if so, call DeviceIoControl with IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX.  This provides the GUID signature of the GPT partition.

In my testing, each partition gives the same signature on a disk, and it matches the signature shown as the uniqueid in diskpart.